# Laravel displaying elements distinctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

```
public function employeebanvisitor(Request $request) { 
    $vis = bookingmodel::distinct('visitorname')
        ->select(
            'id',
            'visitorname',
            'visitorphonenumber',
            'compname',
            'designation'
        )
        ->where('empmail',Auth::user()->email)
        ->get(); 
    return view('employee.employeebanvisitor',compact('vis')); 
}
```

In the above query i need to display the list distinctly where the the distinct element is visitorname.But this command does not return elements distinctly.Any Help or suggestion is most welcomed.

Comment: how about grouping them by visitorname

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
     $vis = bookingmodel::select(
        'id',
        'visitorname',
        'visitorphonenumber',
        'compname',
        'designation'
    )
    ->where('empmail',Auth::user()->email)
    ->distinct('visitorname')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Distinct** does not take any argument in laravel. You can refer to the laravel api. But what you can do is you can set the column that you want to set as distinct to be the first column in your select statement for it to work.

```
$vis = bookingmodel::select(
        'visitorname',
        'id',
        'visitorphonenumber',
        'compname',
        'designation'
    )
    ->distinct()
    ->where('empmail',Auth::user()->email)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Well explained Sir .But Unfortunately it too did not work.I have got suggestions  of using groupBy. But my code actually failed in groupBy too.I expect you a code using groupBy which will be useful for me to give a try.Thank you for your Previous Answer.